# Is there a way to spawn 1 item only once inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

There is one element I want to show only once inside this foreach loop. I was wondering if this was possible or if I would need to change my html/css structure for it with Laravel. I only want to show the icon here once.

example.blade.php :

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
    <p>
        {{ $item }}
        <i class="fa fa-times><!-- this only once --></i>
    </p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Just take it out of the foreach?

Comment: Do `@foreach ($items as $key=>$item)` and only output the icon when `$key==0`.

Comment: You may post this answer so I can accept it :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the comments worked best for me :

```
@foreach ($items as $key => $item)
     {{ $item }}
     @if($key == 0)
         <i class="fa fa-times><!-- this only once --></i>
     @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Ask Chris to post it as an answer so he can take credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
    <p>
        {{ $item }}
        <i class="fa fa-times>
            @if(!isset($iconShown))
            {{ $iconShown = true }}
                DisplayIconHere
            @endif
        </i>
    </p>
@endforeach
```